# How do I add delimiters between strings in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, logging

I have this sample log file here :

```
LOG FILE: 
Jan 1 22:54:17 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:22 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:23 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:41 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
```

The default delimiter is a semi-colon(;) and I want to separate the timestamp and "drop", as well as the "drop" with "%LOGSOURCE%" with that delimiter. I ran the code (see below, it is successful but I didnt get my expected result. This whole code is to insert the delimiter.)

My code:
public class LogParser {

```
    List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

    // while loop
    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
        // find next line
        String token1 = inFile1.next();
        temps.add(token1);
    }
    inFile1.close();

    String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

    for (String s : tempsArray) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})(\\s)(drop)");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            //System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
        //System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: Google : `split with delimiter in java`

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems did you have getting it to work?  On the other hand, looking at your user name, maybe this is the wrong question to ask you

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use a regular expression, you could use:

```
([a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})(\s)(drop)
```

as regex `replaceAll` and replacement would be `$1; $3`.

If you are not running the regex in java and do not need to escape the `\`, then try:

```
([a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\s)(drop)
```

Output:

```
LOG FILE: 
Jan 1 22:54:17; drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:22; drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:23; drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
Jan 1 22:54:41; drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245};
```